# Custom json response body for HTTP errors

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm wondering if there is a way in API Controllers to return a custom object as response body for methods like: `BadRequest()` or `NotFound()`.

For example, for **404** error, I'd like to return something like:

```
{
  "StatusCode": 404,
  "Error": "Not Found",
  "Message": "Custom message..."
}
```

Instead I'm getting this:

```
{
  "Message": "Custom message..."
}
```

At the moment to return complex response body I'm using `Ok()` this way:

```
return Ok(new
{
    Success = false,
    Message = "Custom message...",
    // other fields...
});
```

But obviously I'm returning a **200** status that is not so meaningful.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: They accept a ModelStateDictionary and for anything else they're also virtual!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Long Way

If you need a quick solution just jump to *Short Way*, read this just to understand how it works under the hood. Derive your own `JsonErrorResult` class derived from `JsonResult`:

```
public sealed JsonErrorResult : JsonResult
{
    public JsonErrorResult(StatusCodes statusCode, object value)
        : base(value)
    {
        _statusCode = statusCode;
    }

    private readonly JsonErrorResult StatusCodes _statusCode;
}
```

Now override `ExecuteResultAsync()` method to change status code of default `JsonResult` implementation:

```
public override Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
{
    context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = _statusCode;
    return base.ExecuteResultAsync(context);
}
```

You simply return calling `BadRequest()` you simply do this:

```
return new JsonErrorResult(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, new 
{
    StatusCode = "404",
    Error = "bla bla bla",
    Message = "bla bla bla"
});
```

Of course if you use it often you may want to create your own helper method:

```
protected static JSonErrorResult JsonError(StatusCodes statusCode,
                                           string error, string message)
{
    return new JsonErrorResult(statusCode, new 
    {
        StatusCode = Convert.ToString((int)statusCode),
        Error = error,
        Message = message
    });
}
```

Used like this:

```
return JsonError(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, "bla bla bla", "bla bla bla");
```

## Short Way

`JsonResult` already has `StatusCode` property then your helper method may become like this:

```
protected static JSonResult JsonError(StatusCodes statusCode,
                                           string error, string message)
{
    var result = new JsonResult(new 
    {
        StatusCode = Convert.ToString((int)statusCode),
        Error = error,
        Message = message
    });

    result.StatusCode = (int)statusCode;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a very elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

I usually return something like this:

```
return Json(new { success = false, data = "" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

And then in my AJAX success, I do:

```
if(result.success){
    result.data...
}else{
    //error...
}
```

If you do not want to always send a 200 code, then can you do something like this?

```
//if success...
Response.StatusCode = 200;
return Json(new { responseCode = 200, data = "", message = "..." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

//if failure...
Response.StatusCode = 404;
return Json(new { responseCode = 404, data = "", message = "..." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: This is not so different to what I'm currently doing... you're returning 200 status also for unsuccessful responses...

Answer (score 0):

Create function to deal with error.

```
function AjaxCompletion(xhr) {
    switch (xhr.status) {
        case 200:
            //Your Message
            break;
        case 401: //unauthorize
           //Your desire message
            break;
    }
}
```

And in  `AJAX complete` :

```
  complete: function (xhr) {
            AjaxCompletion(xhr);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your code, it worked (after a while).
It seems that you have written pseudo-code rather than code itself.
So, in order to make life easier to other, here is your same exact code but withing a class which runs.

```
public sealed class JsonErrorResult : JsonResult {

    private readonly HttpStatusCode _statusCode;

    public JsonErrorResult(HttpStatusCode sCode, object value) : base(value) {
        _statusCode = sCode;
    }

    public override Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context) {
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)_statusCode;
        return base.ExecuteResultAsync(context);
    }

    public static JsonResult JsonError(HttpStatusCode statusCode,
                                               string message, string error = "") {
        var result = new JsonResult(new {
            StatusCode = Convert.ToString((int)statusCode),
            Error = error,
            Message = message
        });

        result.StatusCode = (int)statusCode;

        return result;
    }
}
```

and finally you call it like so:

```
return JsonErrorResult.JsonError(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
                                "error msg");
```